# Windows 10 Storage Spaces Poor Speed

Tags: windows-10, performance, raid, storage-spaces

Using Storage Spaces under Windows 10 Pro, I am observing poor, nonsensical speed. A two-way mirror and a simple space across four drives on 2012R2 and 2016TP produce completely different performance characteristics. On my machine, they produce the same performance when benchmarked. I mean literally the exact same. As if striping over four ways is equivalent to mirroring and striping two ways.

I want storage spaces specifically because of the thin pool functionality, and the ability to have an "archive" segment of my four-drive array in parity mode (where I do not care about write speed) to achieve an effective compression of the data (N-1 versus N/2), say for movies/music which are written once and never changed.

Does consumer/workstation Windows storage space not stripe data like the server variant? Is this something I can work around by manually creating my spaces in powershell and setting columns accordingly?

Comment: Read speed should be equivalent. Why wouldn't it be?

Comment: On a four-drive RAID0 versus a RAID10? On a fully optimized solution it would be (I'm not sure if SS stripes reads), however everything is the same (including the writes) and the raw numbers are not RAID-tier. As a test I created two 2-way mirror spaces and software RAID-0'd them with the disk management MMC. That should only decrease performance since SS should already be striping ... but in fact it doubled my performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If created via the GUI then no, Windows 10 does not stripe simple spaces.

In powershell type `get-virtualdisk |fl` and check number of columns.

The Storage Spaces GUI in Win10 is very limited and if you create a storage space using it, it will choose default values which may not suit your intended scenario. Use powershell to manually create storage spaces.

Comment: Then I bet it doesn't stripe two-way mirrors either. F&*% Microsoft decisions. Gonna re-create my spaces with PS as stripes instead of spans I guess.

Comment: Yep, single column for my "RAID10" and "RAID0." Guess I'm gonna fix that.

Comment: @Arthur Kay For 2 way mirror with Powershell, it also does not do read striping.